# Test Accelerometer alignment?

Tags: sensors

Is there any app around that lets an Android user see the "flat" on the accelerometer? The reason I'm looking for such is because I recently got the Need For Speed Shift game. And I notice that the car is veering to the right even if I have the phone held straight. I have to tilt it a little to the left in order for it to go a straight direction which is an awkward workaround. If there's an app that can show a straight line for me to be able to test if my accelerometer is misaligned, please do share. If there's no such app I'll happily accept any hacks/workarounds available like a live wallpaper with a liquid physics on it perhaps?

The sooner I find this out, the better because I can send it in for replacement / repair while it's still under warranty.

Comment: If you have a Samsung Galaxy series device you can try dialing *#0*# to enter a test mode and select `sensor` to see the degrees of the accelerometer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you'd want to confirm something that already seems obvious to you rather than try to calibrate the accelerometer :P

Comment: @MatthewRead, well I was thinking if I had a far clearer display of the accelerometer other than basing it off of a game, I can easily prove to the techs that the accelerometer is indeed misaligned. But as lenik pointed out below, (and something I didn't know), most accelerometers give little miscalibrated readings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an app that I had a while ago, I think they removed it from the market, but I found it here: [Tricorder](http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/app/tricorder). It's a little cheesey and geeky, but if you are in the first section ("GRAV") it will show you the direction vectors from the readings it gets from the accelerometer. It does some other cool things too, but for your diagnostic purposes, it should work well!

**Update:** Here's a screenshot of what you're looking for. I took this while holding my phone horizontally, and you'll notice the "y" vector is 0.040. It kept moving between 0.080 and 0.000. I'd say if it's much more than 0.150 off, you probably have a hardware issue.
[image: Tricorder screenshot]

Here's the reading I got at ~0.500. To get this reading, I held the phone horizontally and lifted up the left side almost a centimeter.  Here's the screenshot, if it helps: 
[image: Tricorder screenshot 2]

Comment: Awesome! I can see that it really is a bit off. I got 0.459 on the Y part. Is it that bad?

Comment: If it's not closer to zero, it's probably off. I'll get that on mine and post another screenshot when I can.

Comment: Yay, Tricorder. I liked it so much that when they removed it from the market, I tracked down the source and built it myself.

Comment: If your device is laying flat on a table, and Y reads 0.459, that's very bad. Are you sure it wasn't 0.0459?